# Java: How to refactor this kind of try-catch block?

Tags: java, refactoring, try-catch, pmd

PMD report that "An instanceof check is being performed on the caught exception. Create a separate catch clause for this exception type." for below code.

```
    String parameter;
    try {
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logFailure(e, parameter);

        if (e instanceof X) {
            throw new A(e);
        } else if (e instanceof Y
                || e instanceof Z) {
            throw new B(e);
        } 
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(e);
    }
```

if i change above code to below, there are 3 duplication of logFailure(e), is there any better way to eliminate this kind of PMD violation?

```
    String parameter;
    try {
        ...
    } catch (X e) {
        logFailure(e, parameter);
        throw new A(e);
    } catch (Y e) {
        logFailure(e);
        throw new B(e);
    } catch (Z e) {
        logFailure(e);
        throw new B(e);
    } catch (exception e) {
        logFailure(e);
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(e);
    }
```

Comment: Java 7 supports multiple catch of exceptions -> catch (IOException|SQLException ex). Maybe you are able to use Java 7.

Comment: Because you seem to be calling the same step logFailure(e) or logFailure(e, parameter) each time, the gang of four, Template Method design pattern jumps to mind

Comment: Java7 is not an option for my application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    String parameter;
    try {
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logFailure(e, parameter);
        throwException(e);
    }

    public void throwException(Exception e) throws Exception{
       if (e instanceof X) {
            throw new A(e);
        } else if (e instanceof Y
                || e instanceof Z) {
            throw new B(e);
        } 
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(e);
    }
```

Additionally you can move `Logger` to this `method`, depends on your design/application

Comment: Very helpful, and throwException can be reused for other methods

Comment: Why an "else" required in `throwException` method?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this : (use an outside try catch)

```
 String parameter;
 try {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logFailure(e, parameter);
        throw e;
    }
 } catch (X e) {
        throw new A(e);
 } catch (Y e) {  
        throw new B(e);
 } catch (Z e) {
        throw new B(e);
 } catch (exception e) {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(e);
 }
}
```

Comment: assume you have 3 or 4 methods in class have the same Exception thrown type, then how it is extendable for all of them?

Comment: Good point but this was a solution for the given try block not the whole class and using instanceof is a hint for not a thorough  design (even for exceptions :))

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
  try{
     // do some thing
    } catch (X |Y |Z | Exception e) {
        logFailure(e, parameter);
        throw new Exception(e);             
    }
```

Comment: You can catch multiple Exception types in single catch as here. but your jdk version should be 7 or higher

Comment: Something like this, but not this.  You can't put subclasses and superclasses in the same multicatch.  Which means it is (X|Y|Z e) or (Exception e) but not both.  More importantly, the same exception isn't always thrown so the blocks can't be merged.